# How to scroll parent window of canvas app to the top?

Tags: iframe, canvas, scroll, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I built a Facebook canvas app that has some fairly long pages. When you scroll to the bottom of the page and click a link it does not send you to the top of the next page. The next page loads and only shows the bottom of it. To make this work correctly I need to scroll the parent window to the top. Is this even possible? If so, how would I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript ScrollTo() method :

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Facebook Documentation, you can tell the Canvas to scroll to X,Y of its page by using FB.Canvas.scrollTo() method. Example:

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the scroll with animate, check this out:

```
if (FB !== undefined){

  FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(pageInfo){
    $({y: pageInfo.scrollTop}).animate(
        {y: 30},
        {duration: 1000, step: function(offset){
            FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, offset);
        }
    });
  });
}
```